# Writing permission with VSFTPD and Centos 6.2

Tags: ftp, httpd, upload, vsftpd, centos6.2

I have a server with centos 6.2 with httpd and vsftpd.

I have few web site in /var/www and i want to add a ftp user for each site.

My user1 home directory is /home/user1 and can read/write to it folder from ftp. (it's the user i use to ssh and almost everything)

I made user2 which home is /var/www/site2 and bash setting /bin/nologin (because i want it to be just a ftp user)

I can log in the FTP with the user2 and download file, but i can't upload file or mkdir...

The permission are :

for /var/www :

`drwxrwxr-x. 13 root root 4096 Aug 21 14:08 .`

for /var/www/site2 :

`drwxrwxrwx. 2 user2 user2 4096 Aug 21 14:35 site2`

(the 777 was just for testing...)

My vsftpd.conf is :

```
 anonymous_enable=NO 
 local_enable=YES
 write_enable=YES 
 local_umask=022
 dirmessage_enable=YES
 xferlog_enable=YES
 connect_from_port_20=YES
 xferlog_std_format=NO
 log_ftp_protocol=YES
 chroot_local_user=YES
 listen=YES
 pam_service_name=vsftpd
 userlist_enable=YES
 tcp_wrappers=YES
 banner_file=/etc/vsftpd/banner
```

My iptables is currently stop for testing, so the problem is not my firewall either...

SELinux is enabled :

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

When i disabled it, it's working! :)
How can I enabled it and keep my vsftpd working?

Thank in advance for your help

Comment: Ug. Doesn't matter what your problem is, it's probably the fault of selinux. I disable it whenever I add anything new, so that I get the brief experience of it working before I re-enable selinux and it kills it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the rights on /var/www/site2?

User2 will need write access to this directory at the file system level. For instance /var/www/site2 needs to be something like:

```
ls /var/www
<snip>
drxwr-xr-x user2  www-data     site2/
```

Make sure SELinux is disabled as well

```
 setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access 1
```

Comment: /var/www
**drwxrwxr-x. 13 root    root      4096 Aug 21 14:08 .**

/var/www/site2
**drwxrwxrwx.  2 user2 user2   4096 Aug 21 14:35 site2**

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: yes  SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted

Comment: Please try disabling SELinux for (just to verify that is/is not the problem).

Comment: You did it! If SELinux is disable, it's working :)  but how can i enable SELinux and having my vsftpd working?

Comment: Please mark the question as answered. To modify your SELinux policy take a look at http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-aa437f65e1c7873cddbafd9e9a73bbf9d102c072 but I can't answer, I use Debian :D

Comment: FYI, I had to set the bool allow_ftpd_full_access to 1 with the command :  **setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access 1**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think making sure that SELinux is disabled is the best approach for this situation.

You need context like `public_content_rw_t` to allow vsftp (etc) to write to the folder with SELinux.

So set the context and then verify with

```
chcon -t public_content_rw_t /var/www/site2
ls -ldZ /var/www/site2/
```

Then check the `/var/log/audit.log` for clues if you still fail. If you still get permission denied issues, and they are getting logged in `/var/log/audit.log`, look into using [audit2allow](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/audit2allow) if you can't figure out what else might help.